# I want to take output of first command as a input of second command in shell

Tags: bash, shell-script

`ls -t1 |  head -n 1` will give me the latest updated file so I want to `tail` that latest updated file in shell. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to open a subshell for the command you want to run and add the result of the command as the parameter of tail:

`tail "$(ls -t1 | head -n 1)"`

Comment: Cool, Its works. Thank you